# Is slightly super linear distortion possible?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Say $H \leq G$ are finitely generated groups (I will keep the generating sets implicit). Is it possible that the distortion of $H$ in $G$ is "quasilinear"? I.e., that we have for all $g\in H$
$$
|g|_H \leq C |g|_G\log |g|_G
$$
but not
$$
|g|_H \leq C' |g|_G
$$
for any $C'$?

Comment: Sure, if $G$ and $H$ are finite. For slightly less trivial example, let $(G,H)$ be any pair for which this is true, and consider the pair $(G\times K,H\times K)$. Of course, there are lots other examples, such as $2\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Z}$, etc. (Perhaps, I misundestand the question though)

Comment: If $H$ is undistorted in $G$ (for example a direct factor $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z^2}$) then it satisfies your inequality.  What are you actually asking?

Comment: I guess that he wants $H$ distorted (i.e., not undistorted). This should indeed be explicit.

Comment: In hyperbolic groups, a distorted subgroup has at least exponential distortion. I don't have a reference to hand, unfortunately.

Comment: Since it does not precisely answer the question, I don't include it in my answer, but for every integer $k>0$ there are embeddings $H\subset G$ of finitely generated nilpotent groups with distortion $\simeq n\mapsto n^{1+1/k}$.

Comment: @HJRW intriguing. Is it easy? well-known? I never heard this.

Comment: @YCor, the only reference I know in the literature is Prop. 2.6 of Ilya  Kapovich's paper "The Combination Theorem and Quasiconvexity" (http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~kapovich/PAPERS/acyl.pdf).  It's not a well known fact, but I think it's implicit in most proofs that qi-embedded implies quasiconvex in hyperbolic groups.  A logarithmic bound arises in those proofs, which is the main point.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, even with $H$ cyclic infinite, you can embed $\mathbf{Z}$ into a finitely generated group with finite generating subset so that the restriction to $\mathbf{Z}$ is (up to equivalence) an arbitrary length function whose balls have at most exponential growth (you obviously have to avoid lengths growing as $\log\log(n)$ since its balls grow as double exponentials). So you can get $|g^n|\simeq n/\log(n)$ or even arbitrarily close to linear.

This is due to A. Olshanskii. I don't have access to his papers (links on his page do not work at the moment), so I'm not sure of references, it at the end of the 90's. There is also a version with embeddings into finitely presented group, with some more conditions on the length function.

---

Here's a simple, explicit example (with $H$ non-cyclic). Consider the lamplighter group $\Gamma$: it is generated by elements $t,(x_n)_{n\in\mathbf{Z}}$ with $x_n$ commuting and $x_n^2=1$, and $tx_nt^{-1}=x_{n+1}$ (so of course it is generated by $\{t,x_0\}$ as well. Consider another copy $\Gamma'$ of $\Gamma$, with similar elements $t',x'_n$. Consider an injective map $s:\mathbf{Z}\to\mathbf{Z}$ with small supralinear growth.

Then consider the HNN extension $$\Lambda=\langle u,\Gamma,\Gamma':ux'_nu^{-1}=x_{s(n)},\forall n\rangle.$$
Then the length in $\Lambda$ of $x_{s(n)}$ is roughly that of $x'_n=t^nx_0^{-n}$, which is roughly $n$, while its length in $\Gamma$ is roughly $s(n)$. Hence (up to some standard details) the distortion of $\Gamma$ in $\Lambda$ is small provided $s$ grows slowly.

Yet, one can ask if there are even more naturally occurring examples.